# clickabe imagemap who show div over the imagemap, the position gets wrong if I add more HTML

Tags: css, css-float

I have a clickabe imagemap who show a div (with html X1 or X2) over the imagemap when I click. The divs should always be at the same spot over the image, but now they change if I add linebreaks in the top of the html . Thats not correct

If I uncomment the first line in the fiddle example (3 linebreaks)

```
      <!-- <br /><br /><br /> -->
```

X1 and X2 will change position, I want they to be at the same spot even if I have 3-4 linebreaks or change the size of the webb browser or something!

To show the X1 and X2 click in the left top corner for X1 and 40px down for X2

I cant it get it to work, any tip/solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/yvsy3ox1/1/

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what are you asking.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to explain better. Have changed the text, I hope you understand what I want now, if not tell me

Comment: give us code WITH your X1 and X2. I can't make anything from only 3 commented <br/> and your jsfiddle link contains only rubbish.

Comment: Sorry
http://jsfiddle.net/yvsy3ox1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolute positioned elements will position themselves relatively to their first parent which has its position set (anything other than the default `static`)

therefore, all you need to do is set a position to the div that contains the image and the X's:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-6/a/images/overview/design_details_left_large.jpg" usemap="#foo" />
    <div id="divcar1" class="divcar1">x1</div>
    <div id="divcar2" class="divcar2">x2</div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you need to add `position:absolute;` to your div and then try to position it.

Comment: Can you post the full code so that it becomes a little bit more clear.

Comment: Its the almost the full code, the rest of the code is a  webbform only!
Try to uncomment the first line in the fiddle and  you will see that the position of x1 and x2 will be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Your container div must have relative positioning:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}

<div class="container">
    <img src="http://images.apple.com/v/iphone-6/a/images/overview/design_details_left_large.jpg" usemap="#foo"/>

    <div id="divcar1" class="divcar1">x1</div>
    <div id="divcar2" class="divcar2">x2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6t9eka/